# recuperar nome de um background de uma textView

Tags: android

Caso seja possível, como faço para recuperar o nome de um background de uma textView ? (android)

tenho um textView e gostaria de recuperar o nome do arquivo que seria (back_corDoFundo) de preferência em String para comprar com outra String, já tentei getBackground() e dá erro. Alguém pode me ajudar ?

obrigado

Comment: Provavelmente não é possível. O que você poderia conseguir seria o resource ID (uma constante numérica na classe `R`) correspondente ao arquivo de background, mas a única informação disponível é o `Drawable` usado no background (via `getBackground()`), e acredito que o sistema não tem necessidade de preservar essa informação junto com o `Drawable`, tanto que a classe `Drawable` não tem um `getResourceId()` ou nada do tipo.

Comment: Outra forma seria guardar a string no arquivo `strins.xml` e capturar depois com o método `findViewById(R.string.string_background)`, e utiliza-la para definir o background do textView.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit

Como foi esclarecido nos comentários, a forma proposta anteriormente não atende.

Logo estou propondo outra, usando estados customizados, acredito eu que uma forma mais limpa e correta.

Os passos são os seguintes:

1. Primeiro precisamos criar uma `Custom View` que extenda qualquer uma que use para representar seu quadrado na palavra cruzada. No meu caso, é uma subclasse de `TextView`.

   ```
   public class PalavraCruzadaTextView extends TextView {

       private static final int[] ERRADO_STATE_SET = {R.attr.state_errado};
       private static final int[] CORRETO_STATE_SET = {R.attr.state_correto};
       private static final int[] PALAVRA_STATE_SET = {R.attr.state_palavra};

       boolean correto, errado, palavra;

       public RobotoTextView(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       public RobotoTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       }

       @Override
       protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
           // Chama o metodo da superclasse para tratar os estados comuns
           // Passando o espaco + 3, por causa dos nossos estados customizados
           final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 3);


           if (isCorreto()) {
               mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CORRETO_STATE_SET);
           }

           if (isErrado()) {
               mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, ERRADO_STATE_SET);
           }

           if (isPalavra()) {
               mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, PALAVRA_STATE_SET);
           }

           return drawableState;
       }

       public boolean isCorreto() {
           return correto;
       }

       public boolean isErrado() {
           return errado;
       }

       public boolean isPalavra() {
           return palavra;
       }

       public void setCorreto(boolean correto) {
           this.correto = correto;

           // Atualiza o estado do drawable
           refreshDrawableState();
       }

       public void setErrado(boolean errado) {
           this.errado = errado;

           // Atualiza o estado do drawable
           refreshDrawableState();
       }

       public void setPalavra(boolean palavra) {
           this.palavra = palavra;

           // Atualiza o estado do drawable
           refreshDrawableState();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Com isso é preciso definir os estados que a `PalavraCruzadaTextView` pode ter, em termos de xml. Coloque em seu arquivo `/res/values/attrs.xml` (ou crie) a seguinte declaração:

   ```
   <declare-styleable name="PalavraCruzadaTextView">
       <attr name="state_errado" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="state_correto" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="state_palavra" format="boolean" />
   </declare-styleable>
   ```

   Isso define os 3 possíveis estados customizados que a `PalavraCruzadaTextView` pode ter.
3. Para definir um background para a `PalavraCruzadaTextView`, levando em consideração os estados, basta fazer:

   ```
   <nome.do.pacote.PalavraCruzadaTextView
       android:id="@+id/palavra_cruzada_text_view"
       android:width="wrap_content"
       android:height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/background_palavra_cruzada" />
   ```
4. A definição do background_palavra_cruzada.xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item app:state_correto="true">
           <!-- Define o Drawable para o estado correto -->
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/green" />
           </shape>
       </item>

       <item app:state_errado="true">
           <!-- Define o Drawable para o estado errado -->
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/red" />
           </shape>
       </item>

       <!-- Como temos outro estado combinando esses dois,
            eh preciso forçar o false para nao sobrepor -->
       <item app:state_palavra="true" android:state_pressed="false">
           <!-- Define o Drawable para o estado palavra -->
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
           </shape>
       </item>

       <!-- Pode-se combinar com outros estados -->
       <item app:state_palavra="true" android:state_pressed="true">
           <!-- Define o Drawable para o estado palavra -->
           <shape android:shape="rectangle">
               <solid android:color="@color/orange" />
           </shape>
       </item>
   </selector>
   ```
5. E para mudar os estados:

   ```
   PalavraCruzadaTextView pl = (PalavraCruzadaTextView) findViewById(R.id.palavra_cruzada_text_view);

   pl.setCorreto(...);
   pl.setErrado(...);
   pl.setPalavra(...);

   // E para saber o estado atual:

   pl.isCorreto();
   pl.isErrado();
   pl.isPalavra();
   ```

### Referências:

1. [Custom drawing states possible?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo/discussion)

---

Outra solução poderia ser:

Ao usar o atributo `@color/back_corDoFundo` você criou uma referência. A partir do momento que seu Layout foi inflado, a referência é "resolvida" e vira um valor de cor de 4 bytes que não tem nenhum identificador.

O background de uma `View` é um `Drawable`, dependendo da subclasse há uma forma diferente de conseguir a cor.

O fato de usar o atributo `background="@color/...` o `LayoutInflater` cria um [`ColorDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html) que represente esta cor, cada tipo de `Drawable` para esse atributo vai gerar uma subclasse diferente. E nessa subclasse é possível obter a cor de forma fácil.

O que você pode fazer é:

```
// Pego o background da View
Drawable background = suaView.getBackground();

// Pego a cor na representação em 4 bytes relativa a sua cor no resource 
int corDoFundo = getResources().getColor(R.color.back_corDoFundo);

// Como voce usou o @color/back_corDoFundo, a subclasse eh ColorDrawable
ColorDrawable = cBackground = (ColorDrawable) background;

// Comparo as duas cores
if(corDoFundo == cBackground.getColor()) {
    // A cor do fundo da View e back_corDoFundo
}
```

Cuidado!! Qualquer mudança nesse atributo pode gerar uma subclasse diferente. E ai a abordagem deve ser diferente!

Se você usar um `Drawable State List`, sendo o xml por exemplo:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" />
</selector>
```

Nesse caso o `LayoutInflater` criará um `Drawable` cuja subclasse é [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html), onde ele tem dois estados. Onde cada estado é um `ColorDrawable`.

E assim por diante...

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo empenho de me responder e pela atenção, sou iniciante, acho que me expressei mal, eu gostaria de recuperar o nome do arquivo que está de background, cor de fundo é a característica que usei pra identificá-los pois eles mudam, eu preciso recuperar para saber qual o atual e em função disso tomar uma ação entende ? meus textView trabalham apenas com um arquivo de background, não são coloridos.

Comment: @Luciano, não muito bem entendi não... Vou complementar a minha resposta. Mas coloque esses detalhes em sua pergunta. E se puder um trecho de código pra exemplificar melhor.

Comment: meu código está no computador de casa, mais tarde eu coloco, mas sendo mais específico, é uma palavra cruzada, então os quadrados ficam verdes se a letra estiver certa e vermelho se errado, e os quadrados que formam uma determinada palavra ficam laranja, então eu preciso saber sempre qual arquivo está sendo usado em determinado quadrado(textview) pq assim vou saber a cor que aparece pro usuários(background) e então comparar com uma string(cor) e saber qual cor deve ser colocada no quadrado ou se não deve ser trocado

Comment: Você pode fazer como eu escrevi (verificar pelo valor  da cor) e mudar o background quando precisar `setBackgroundColor`. Complicando um pouco, a idéia mais correta seria criar estados customizados (p.e: state_correto, state_palavra, state_errado, tipo o state_pressed, state_checked e etc) e setá-los no background conforme o estado do TextView. Nesse caso teria um `State List Drawable` com uma cor diferente para cada estado desses. Você só teria que extender o TextView para setar esses estados como no exemplo: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/uqr2BNI7NZo/discussion

Comment: @Luciano, alterei minha resposta, incluindo a forma como disse. Se tiver alguma dúvida na implementação me avise.